# How can I get a template to replace, rather than append to, the existing one?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to navigate from my home page to another page (template) in my Meteor app.

I installed the iron:router package and added the following code:

First, this template (placeholder content) in my html file:

```
<template name="scheduleOpenExisting">
    <h2>Open Existing Schedule</h2>
</template>
```

Then this in my .js file:

```
Router.route('/scheduleOpenExisting');
```

...and finally this to a menu item:

```
<li><a href="{{pathFor route='scheduleOpenExisting'}}">Open Existing</a></li>
```

...which I changed from:

```
<li> <a href="#">Open Existing</a>
```

When I select that menu item, it does change the URL from http://localhost:3000/ to http://localhost:3000/scheduleOpenExisting, but it appends the scheduleOpenExisting template to the bottom of the page, rather than navigating to a new page, or in an Ajaxy way replacing the existing content.

So how can I get the scheduleOpenExisting template to replace, rather than append to, the "home page"?

### UPDATE

I haven't had time to test it yet (this is a home project, and I had to go to work), but I moved all my code out of the single .html and .js files into various places:

```
Scheduler
    Client (folder)
        main.html (moved the two templates from scheduler.html for the "first page" here)
        main.js (moved the .isClient code from scheduler.js here)
        Templates (folder)
            openExistingSchedule.html (contains a template; will add more later, as the project grows)
    Server (folder)
        scheduler.js (moved the .isServer code here)
```

...and will see if it still works, and works any differently, with this new project structure.

### UPDATE 2

It still does the same thing, even with the revamped structure - the template is inserted at the bottom of the page.

Nevertheless, it's really great that Meteor still runs just fine after moving the files all over creation. Other environments would be likely to break, and throw misleading err msgs when doing such a thing.

### UPDATE 3

In \client\main.html, I've got this:

```
<head>
    <TITLE>Crew Scheduler</TITLE>
</head>

<body TEXT="#000000">

<div class="container">
    {{> mnuScheduler}}
    {{> tblScheduler}}
</div>

</body>

<template name="mnuScheduler">
    <ul class="top-level-menu">
        <li> <a href="#">Schedules</a>
            <ul class="second-level-menu">
                <li><a href="{{pathFor route='scheduleOpenExisting'}}">Open Existing</a></li>
 . . .<template name="tblScheduler">. . .
```

In \client\templates\openExistingSchedule.html I've got this:

```
<template name="scheduleOpenExisting">
    <h2>Open Existing Schedule</h2>
</template>
```

...and in \client\routing.js I've got this:

```
Router.route('/scheduleOpenExisting');
```

Comment: What is your home page code? If it is pure HTML code (not in a template) Meteor will always use it first... Do you have a `main` template?

Comment: It is in a template. I have no "main" template. But anyway, based on how it's working now, it seems like moving from one "page" (template) to another will simply append the new one beneath the last...

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Have you tried defining a default Template layout for the router, and a different one for a different route?

Comment: @ArchWilhes: No; do you have a link that explains how to do that (a tutorial, or such)?

Comment: Could you please post a repro, an MCVE?

Comment: I'll try to do that this weekend if my new project structure (see the Update in my question for what I did) hasn't oriented things north.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Perhaps you'd [find this useful](http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/iron-router-part-1/)?

Comment: @ArchWilhes: Funny, that's what I used as my "jumping off" (or "jumping into") point for this.